# Find a set which has GLB and LUB but there exists at least one subset which has no GLB and LUB

Tags: real-analysis, boolean-algebra

GLB=greatest lower bound
LUB=least upper bound
Give one example of a set such that the GLB and LUB exist but there exists at least one subset which has no GLB and LUB.

Comment: Hmm, is the set supposed to be a set of reals? The [tag:real-analysis] tag suggests that it is, but [tag:boolean-algebra] could imply that you're thinking about a more general order-theoretic setting.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the set $\{42\}$. It has a greatest lower bound and a least upper bound (both of which are $42$), but its subset $\varnothing$ has neither.

Comment: A more non-trivial example? In the real line, this cannot happen non-trivially, right?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: Correct. If the original set has both upper and lower bounds, then all of its subsets are bounded, and so every _non-empty_ subset will have a GLB and LUB.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but what would be an example of an ordered set where this would be the case? That set certainly cannot have the GLB/LUB property, right?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: Obviously not -- but for example in $\mathbb Q$ we could consider $\{x\mid -2<x<2\}$ and its subset $\{x\mid x^2<2\}$. (That subset has a GLB and LUB in $\mathbb R$, of course, but not if $\mathbb Q$ is all we know).

Comment: Oh yes, that is correct. The GLB may exist, but we can not say it exists within the given set. That is a clear example.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the partially ordered set
$$P=\{1,2,3,5,12,18,72,108,1080\}$$
ordered by divisibility. The set $X=\{5,12,18\}$ has greatest lower bound $1$ and least upper bound $1080,$ but its subset $Y=\{12,18\}$ has neither a greatest lower bound nor a least upper bound in $P.$